# How to find out if X is present in all three list in python in one statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1=["X","2","3"]
list2={"4","X","6"]
list3={"7","8","X"]
if [list[1],list1[1],list2[2]] in ['X','X','X']:
   print("Value X avbl in all lists")
```

Please help with a single statement which can help in this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `all` which returns a `True` if all conditions are a truthy:

```
if all('X' in lst for lst in [list1, list2, list3]):
   print("Value X avbl in all lists")
```